# How to move OS from HDD to SSD using only command line and without using live boot disk or cd?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I am 3000 miles away from this server which had an SSD installed, and now I would like to move the OS (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) from the HDD (basically a RAID array of SAS drives) to the SSD (SATA). I need to do this completely on the command line as I will not be able to actually be at the device or boot from any disk or USB. How can I accomplish this?

I am considering trying to just cp * /mnt/ssd, but I feel like this would be insufficient. Any help is appreciated.

I have tried:
http://www.sesser.eu/howtos/hdd2ssd.php

but it fails at:
`sudo gparted /dev/sdc`

with the error:

````
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gpartedbin:14614): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:36:09.912: cannot open display:```
````

Comment: GParted is a (Gnome) graphical app therefore it need a graphical environment, that's what the "cannot open display" error message is about.

Comment: To expand on what @ChanganAuto said, you *could* use x11 forwarding to accomplish the "cannot open display" problem but you are still left with a can of worms as how to tell your MB firmware to now boot from the other device?

Comment: @Señor CMasMas  I have a dell server running iDrac 7, can I not use that to edit the firmware settings?

Comment: You could perhaps duplicate manually the partition setup (size & type) on the SSD, then use [TimeShift](https://www.linuxtechi.com/timeshift-backup-restore-ubuntu-linux/) to create a full snapshot of the HDD and restore it to the SSD, then finally change the GRUB config to boot from the SSD. The problem is of course if the computer crashes while you're 3000 miles away...

Answer (score 0):

Your objective might be technically possible but **the risk is extremely high**  As you are stumbling at the first hurdle the chances of you succeeding are very low. **Don't do this if you have anything to lose, and back up first if you do**.

Your immediate problem is easily solvable by using `parted` rather than `GParted`.  Or you could use another partition manager like `gfdisk` or `fdisk`.  But really, this is the easy part.

The biggest risk/challenge you are likely to face if you don't have knowledgeable remote hands (and there are likely hurdles on the way), will be getting your system to boot off the new drive in place of the old one.  You may need to modify the BIOS / UEFI as well. That may not be possible remotely.

Of-course, there may be other strategies which can work, but are system dependent - like converting the raid to the ssd using the raid subsystem or doing a full block copy - but it's not possible to advise how this might be done with the limited information provided.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out...

Here is what I did...

- I backed up the files by basically doing scp * /remote_directory in the root folder
- Then I have iDRAC hardware controller, which you can login remotely, to load remotely a virtual ISO - ubuntu server live image
- I then installed the operating system on the SSD
- Then through iDrac, I changed the boot order to boot to BIOS
- I changed the boot order in the bios to boot from SSD
- I then mounted the old filesystem as LVM and copied the contents to the new filesystem, then deleted the old stuff

Seems to work, only thing I may do in the future is to compress the files before backing them up...

Thank you everyone for your help!

I never recommend anyone getting a server from Dell, but I will say the iDRAC utility is quite convenient.